# White text in Sublime Text

Tags: colors, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I downloaded Sublime text from them website and my code still white, I don't know why. I unistalled and reinstalled it 3 times, tried to install themes packages etc I don't understand what is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens when Sublime Text doesn't know which syntax highlighting to choose. First of all Sublime Text guesses the syntax from the file extension. E.g. if you have a file named `my_file_name.php` Sublime Text assumes that the PHP syntax highlighting is the best.

In your picture the file name is `script_connection` without any file extension so Sublime Text doesn't know which syntax it is. You can select a syntax from the menu `View » Syntax` or press <kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type `Set Syntax`. Another way is to click the syntax name (probably `Plain Text`) on the right bottom corner of Sublime Text and select a syntax format.

Comment: Indeed i just added .py at the end of the file it worked thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when we insert Html and css and php codes in one file and as a default Sublime highlight the html and css codes because sublime knows just know html and css codes so we should open sublime application and select view from navigation bar and select syntax and then select php it will knows all types of tags and elements and highlight all.
`Sublime` => `View` => `Syntax` => `PHP`