# Why was the code in the Sublime Text 3 painted white?

Tags: html, sublimetext3

I work with someone else's code. The code is very simple and correct, but for some reason, a small piece of code was painted by an editor in white, and not as usual. Does anyone know in which cases Sublime Text 3 colors the code white?

[image: Sublime Text 3]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238637/white-text-in-sublime-text

Comment: Oh, huh. That's... bizarre. The exact same fragment in the production site highlights just fine on the browser.

Comment: @Nima Derakhshanjan: I don't think so. Here you can see quite clearly that the rest of the file is highlighted, as Sublime can tell it's an HTML document. It's just one portion of it that's not.

Comment: IIRC Sublime Text skips highlighting on very long lines. It’d be for performance reasons.

Comment: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/xml-syntax-highlight-does-not-work-for-long-lines/16435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text doesn’t apply syntax highlighting to lines [starting at 16384 characters](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/513). All of that white text you see is a single line in the source, wrapped for display.

This limit isn’t configurable and you can’t necessarily reformat the HTML without changing what it represents, but if you just wanted to know why – that’s it. :)